# Free module as a direct sum

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $ F$ be a free $R$-module,with basis $w_1,..,w_n$.  Then for $x \in F $ we have that $ x=w_1r_1+...+w_nr_n$ with $r_i \in R$ ,and  $w_1,..,w_n$ are linearly independent over $R$. I have to prove that:  $$F=w_1R \oplus  ...\oplus w_nR$$

My idea is to prove that $w_iR \cap (w_1R+...+w_{i-1}R+w_{i+1}R...+w_nR) =0$ so the sum became direct sum.Is that the correct way and if it is how can i prove that?

Comment: That's correct. You have to prove the assertion by proving that if the intersection contaion a nonzero element, there is a linear relation between the $w_i$.

Comment: thanks Bernard. Let $x \in w_iR \cap (w_1R+..+w_nR)$ then $ x=w_ir_i$ and  $ x=w_1r_1+..+w_nr_n$ .How there exist a linear relation?

Comment: Translate $x=x$ using two different ways for writing $x$. Btw the second way of writing $x$ doesn't involve $w_i$.